# Ubuntu 14.04 - LibreOffice Writer doesn't have visible minimize, maximize and close buttons

Tags: unity, libreoffice, 14.04

Window menu for LibreOffice Writer is locked under Unity global menu bar.

If I go in System Settings → Appearance → Behavior and I checked "Show the menu for a window in the window's title bar" then no menu is visible for LibreOffice Writer. Also the LibreOffice Writer's window cannot be dragged with mouse from the global menu.

What should I do to solve these problems: unlock the office menu (to have visible minimize, maximize and close buttons) and to be able to drag the window? Thank you.

Comment: This problem is also solved for me with this simple solution! The problem was only with Writer in a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Alt+F7

The keyboard shortcut to move a window is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

To use this, click somewhere within the misbehaving libreoffice window to make sure it has focus.

Then use the keyboard short cut.  The mouse grab will occur - just move you mouse downwards to move the window from under the panel.

Other useful shortcuts can be viewed in the System Settings - Keyboard window

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just moving once the window and then I can drag the window and I can see complete window menu bar. Is also working after restarting the application. For me it is solved!