# Always show menu in LibreOffice

Tags: unity, libreoffice, gtk

I'd like to always see the application menu, but by default that's hidden until I mouse onto the top line of the screen. Perhaps this is aesthetically pleasing, but it sucks in terms of usability.

I saw [this old question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219491/why-no-menu-bar-in-libreoffice) about the same problem but the solutions there must be outdated. At least they don't work on my 14.04 system.

The [purge-and-reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452653/libre-office-is-opening-without-menus?rq=1) trick didn't work for me, it's the same as before.

**How can I make the LibreOffice application menu always be visible?**

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450412/ubuntu-14-04-libreoffice-writer-doesnt-have-visible-minimize-maximize-and-cl) answer your question or does [this](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/33010/ubuntu-1404-where-is-the-tools-menu/) do it?

Comment: @Korkel sorry but those links seem completely unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the global menu for all applications. Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu).

You can also make the menu appear on the window title bar, by going to Appearance > Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this question is very specific about always displaying the menu in LibreOffice, you now have the ability in 14.04 (as long as you are fully up-to-date) to switch on the global & local window menus permanently on a Unity wide basis.

This ability was back-ported from 15.04 which has this ability (and is set permanently on)

To switch on permanently:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true
```

To switch off i.e. to autohide:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus False
```